# Streamlit sidebars

Tags: python, streamlit

I'm trying to add two independent sidebars to a streamlit site. The problem is that I want the user to be able to select only one of the options. If I create two times:

```
menu1 = st.sidebar.radio("Menu1", ["A"])
menu2 = st.sidebar.radio("Menu2", ["B"])
```

and the user clicks option "B" from menu2, option "A" will be displayed above it.

I've tried adding blank space to one sidebar, but it's clickable, which I don't want it to be because it doesn't look user frienldy.